# Global var not testable

Tags: javascript, web-testing, canoo

I cant pass a test because canoo does not support global variables in extrenal js-file.

index.html:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="index.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <button onclick="alert(a+1);">asldkf</button>

   </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var a=1;
```

CanooWebtest throws:

```
JavaScript error loading page 
http://localhost:8080/index.html: 
  ReferenceError: "a" is not defined. (JavaScriptStringJob#1)
```

Any suggesstions?

Comment: I wouldn't try executing that script until the document is loaded and ready.

Comment: You should NOT use empty tag notation with script elements since [not all browsers handle it properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work).

Comment: @jbabey, ok, iv edited my question, the error comes anyway.

Comment: @epascarello, ok, iv edited my question, the error comes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could always trick it and add it to one of the global objects - Window, Document...
Not a good solution but should work.

```
<script>
    window.a = 1;
</script>
```

Comment: if also changed the js-file to window.a=1;
Still: "a" is not defined.

Comment: Yes, 'a' is not defined, but 'window.a' should be.

Comment: But isnt. commentsmustbeatleast15charactersinlength